# How to say bathe a dog in British English?

Tags: british-english

It seems that "bathe" is used this way only in American English. So, how does one express the same idea in British English?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use 'bathe' in British English?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most commonly used expression is “**give someone a bath**” (in both AE and BE), but I wouldn’t mind saying “**give someone a shower**”.

> I think you should give your dog a bath.
>
> I think you should give your dog a shower.

We can use both but remember the first expression is more common. Even in British English we would say “bath a dog”.

[image]
<sub>Definition from Oxford Languages</sub>

Comment: _Bathe a dog_ would be acceptable in British English, though _bath_ is probably more common.

Answer (score 2):

In British English, the verb is the same as American "Bathe" pronounced /beɪð/ is common and idiomatic. For example

> [How Often Should I Bathe My Dog?](https://www.ukpets.com/blog/how-often-should-i-bathe-my-dog/)
>   UK Pets Blog/
>   Healthcare and Grooming